# C - synchronizing multiple threads w/ mutexs

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads, mutex

I'm trying to synchronize multiple (7) threads. I thought I understood how they work until I was trying it on my code and my threads were still printing out of order. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>
void *text(void *arg);
long code[] = {4,6,3,1,5,0,2}; //Order in which to start threads
int num = 0;
pthread_mutex_t lock; //Mutex variable

int main()
{
    int i;
    pthread_t tid[7];

    //Check if mutex worked
    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0){
        printf("Mutex init failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //Initialize random number generator
    time_t seconds;
    time(&seconds);
    srand((unsigned int) seconds);

    //Create our threads
    for (i=0; i<7; i++)
        pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, text, (void*)code[i]);

    //Wait for threads to finish
    for (i=0; i<7; i++){
        if(pthread_join(tid[i], NULL)){
            printf("A thread failed to join\n");
        }
    }    
    //Destroy mutex
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&lock);

    //Exit main
    return 0;
}

void *text (void *arg)
{
    //pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); //lock

    long n = (long) arg;
    int rand_sec = rand() % (3 - 1 + 1) + 1; //Random num seconds to sleep
    while (num != n) {} //Busy wait used to wait for our turn
    num++; //Let next thread go
    sleep(rand_sec); //Sleep for random amount of time

    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock); //lock
    printf("This is thread %d.\n", n);

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock); //unlock
    //Exit thread
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

So here I am trying to make threads 0-6 print IN ORDER but right now they are still scrambled. The commented out mutex lock is where I originally had it, but then moved it down to the line above the print statement but I'm having similar results. I am not sure where the error in my mutex's are, could someone give a hint or point me in the right direction? I really appreciate it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please explain why you think that your threads should print 'in order'?  All you have done is put a lock round the printf(), which has its own internal lock anyway.

Comment: @MartinJames from what I understand, the lock will restrict other threads from doing anything until the current thread is finished.

Comment: @donutjuice: Then you don't understand correctly. (Successfully) locking a mutex will prevent other threads from acquiring it until you release it, that's all. Nothing at all to do with "until the current thread is finished". And since you make all your threads sleep for a random time before trying to acquire the mutex, then even ignoring that fact that you can't predict in which order threads will run in general, you're going out of your way to try to make them not run in order. Nothing you are doing with the mutex prevents or attempts to prevent this.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths can you give me an idea of how I should be using the mutex then? I tried putting the lock at the top of the function (the commented out lock statement) but when I did that, no threads printed.

Comment: @donutjuice: Mutexes are for synchronizing access to shared resources, not for synchronizing the execution of threads. You shouldn't be using them for this purpose at all. It's the accesses to `num` that should be protected by mutexes. You synchronize the execution of threads with condition variables.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths I put the lock statement right above the line `num++;` and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @donutjuice: Suggest asking your professor, then, since after all you're in school to learn. It's still the wrong way to solve the problem. But the most glaring problem with your code is that after your "busy wait used to wait for our turn", you immediately "let [the] next thread go" and go to sleep before you actually do anything with your turn. Before you even get to dealing with mutexes, doesn't that look obviously problematic to you?

Comment: @PaulGriffiths that was pre-written code. I had to implement the mutexs to solve the synchronization issue. I was instructed to not edit existing code, just to use mutexs to synchronize the threads (which I was able to accomplish since posting this question)

Comment: @donutjuice I think this is a very good pthread tutorial: https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/

Comment: @donutjuice Your code aside, this problem does not fit the paradigm for a threaded model at all. You said you want to make the threads print in order from 0-6. The benefit of threads is to make them run in PARALLEL, not SEQUENTIALLY. Printing out values from 0-6 in order is a sequential operation. Making that happen with threads would be overkill and take longer and be more of a headache than simply having a single thread do it. You should only be using threads if you have a problem that can be divided up in chunks that are independent of each other. If this is a proof-of-concept to see (cont)

Comment: (cont) threads work, then have each one count to a billion or something and see which order they finish in. If you want to see a mutex work, then have half your threads increment a value and the other half decrement, both with and without mutex protection (still not a parallel problem but you will get the idea). I can say from experience, only use threads when you HAVE to. Threads open the door for all kinds of crazy, strange, hard-to-figure-out bugs that happen once in a blue moon. If you have a problem that can be reasonably solved using a single thread, it is NOT cool to introduce more.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot make threads to run in order with only a mutex because they go in execution in an unpredictable order.
In my approach I use a condition variable and a shared integer variable to create a queueing system. Each thread takes a number and when the `current_n` number is equal to the one of the actual thread, it enters the critical section and prints its number.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define N_THREAD 7

int current_n = 0;

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_cond_t number = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;


void *text (void *arg) {
   int i = (int)arg;

   pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
   while ( i > current_n ) {
      pthread_cond_wait(&number, &mutex);
   }

   //i = current_n at this point

   /*I use stderr because is not buffered and the output will be printed immediately.
     Alternatively you can use printf and then fflush(stdout).
   */
   fprintf(stderr, "I'm thread n=%d\n", i);
   current_n ++;

   pthread_cond_broadcast(&number);
   pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
   return (void*)0;
}

int main() {
   pthread_t tid[N_THREAD];

   int i = 0;
   for(i = 0; i < N_THREAD; i++) {
      pthread_create(&tid[i], NULL, text, (void *)i);
   }

   for(i = 0; i < N_THREAD; i++) {
      if(pthread_join(tid[i], NULL)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "A thread failed to join\n");
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
I'm thread n=0
I'm thread n=1
I'm thread n=2
I'm thread n=3 
I'm thread n=4
I'm thread n=5
I'm thread n=6
```

Compile with
`gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 test.c -o test -lpthread`

Don't worry about the warnings.